# adb shell input text with space not working

Tags: adb, gboard

```
adb shell input text 'Hindustan%sTrading%sCompany'
```

Gives `Company` in Gboard

```
adb shell input text 'Hindustan%s'
```

Just gives a space

`adb shell input text '%sHindustan'` is working fine.

so word before `%s` is missing

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.40
Version 28.0.2-5303910
```

Comment: Try using double quotes ("...") and putting real space instead of %s in the input.

Comment: Same on double quote.
Real space never worked

Comment: It works for me. Which version of Android are you using?

Comment: Which one ? Lollipop , which keyboard u using

Comment: I am using the hard keyboard of my PC.

Comment: I am using the latest version of Google keyboard (GBoard).

Comment: ADB version is 1.0.41. And yours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems fixed

```
λ adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 30.0.4-6686687
```

The following works as expected

```
adb shell input text 'Hindustan%sTrading%sCompany'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try separating the *input* lines like this:

```
adb shell input text 'Hindustan'
adb shell input text '%s'
adb shell input text 'Trading'
adb shell input text '%s'
adb shell input text 'Company'
```

Comment: Only Hindustan.
Did you get the correct one?

Comment: is this the correct way? with many adb shell input text lines?

Comment: did you get the correct output? Just a workaround